# ElasticSearch and searching on multiple fields in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using the latest version of [elasticsearch-php](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-php) as well as the latest version of MongoDB and ElasticSearch.

I need to do a search on multiple fields that can contain one or multiple values. Example:

country_code should be either NL, BE or DE
AND
category should contain be AA01, BB01, CC02 or ZZ11

I thought I would solve it as followed (PHP):

```
$countries = array(“NL”, “BE”, “DE”);
$category = array(“AA01”, “BB01”, “CC02”, “ZZ11”);

$searchParams['body']['query']['bool']['must']['terms']['country'] = $countries;
$searchParams['body']['query']['bool']['must']['terms']['categories'] = $category;
$searchParams['body']['query']['bool']['must']['terms']['minimum_should_match'] = 1;
```

But the result does not even come close the the data that I expect to get back.

Sometimes *$countries* and/or *$category* can only have one element.

Comment: That is because of how arrays in PHP work, you are overwriting the  `terms` key each time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is becaue of how PHP arrays work, you are overwriting the `terms` query each time, instead try something along the lines of:

```
array(
    'body' => array('query' => 
    'bool' => array(
        'must' => array(
            array('terms' => array('country' => implode(' ', $countries))),
            array('terms' => array('category' => implode(' ', $category))),
        )
    )
))
```

`minimum_should_match` is useless with `must` clause of the query.

Comment: "you are overwriting the terms query each time" - so obvious. Thanks @Sammaye.

Comment: As a side note 

This: array('country' => implode(' ', $countries)) does not seem to work, but array('country' => $countries) goes fine.

Comment: Is it possible to specify an array there without imploding it ?

Comment: @HappyCoder I don' believe so, it was one of the things that confused me about ES: that you culd not query by tjhe structure of it's own schema, among other things