# Elastic search 1.4 and Drupal 7 : use array in query

Tags: php, elasticsearch, drupal

in PHP Drupal, I wish to make a request which looks in the field 'field_xxx' with several identifying: id=106 **AND** id=105 (like a filter).
 
I tried diverse solutions unsuccessfully.
 
Could anybody help me? Thank you very much

```
$searchParams = [
    'index' => 'indextest,
    'type' => 'index_test',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [ 'match' => [ 'title' => 'the cat' ] ],
                    [ 'match' => [ 'field_xxx' => ['106','105'] ] ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];



$searchParams['body']['query']['match']['title'] = "Le jeu de la dame";
$searchParams['body']['query']['bool']['must']['field_support']= '106,105';
```

Comment: I tried : [ 'term' => [ 'field_support' => '106']  ] it's ok

Comment: but i have an error to : [ 'term' => [ 'field_support' => '106','105' ]  ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `terms` query will be useful.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818516/elasticsearch-and-searching-on-multiple-fields-in-php)